# El juego del chango

Tags: c#, .net, poo

me puse a practicar un poco con la POO, porque no domino mucho el escenario y queria poner en practica algunos conocimientos que tengo. Realice un pequeño juego donde  a un chango se le da de comer fruta (Clase padre), entre esas frutas se tiene la Banana y el Limon(clases heredadas), si el chango comio Banana el chango reacciona de forma diferente a como comio Limon.

El detalle que en estos momentos tengo es que no se porque no puedo acceder a los valores del sabor y tamaño de la fruta.

En otro caso me gustaria dejar el codigo por aca y aceptar sugerencias sobre el mismo para saber si en general esta bien implementado o si no es la forma del todo correcta de hacer el ejercicio, en especial la forma a la que accedo a los tipos de datos para distinguir que esta comiendo el chango.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido al Mundo de Changos");
        Chango chang1 = new Chango();
        Banana ban1 = new Banana("Grande","Dulce");
        chang1.Eat(ban1);

        Chango chang2 = new Chango();
        Limon lim1 = new Limon("pequeña","acida");
        chang2.Eat(lim1);

    }
}
/////// Tipo de alimento
class Fruta
{
    private string fsize;
    public string size
    {
        get { return fsize;}
        set { fsize = value;}
    }

    private string fflavor;
    public string flavor
    {
        get { return fflavor;}
        set { fflavor = flavor;}
    }
    public Fruta(string size, string flavor)
    {
        this.size = size;
        this.flavor = flavor;
    }

}
////////// Frutas
class Banana : Fruta
{
    public Banana(string size, string flavor ):base(size, flavor) 
    {

    }
}   

class Limon : Fruta
{
    public Limon(string size, string flavor):base(size,flavor)
    {

    }
}

/////// El Chango
class Chango
{

    public void Sad(Fruta fruta){
        Console.WriteLine ("El changuito esta triste porque no le gusta " + fruta.GetType())  ;
    }

    public void Happy(Fruta fruta){
        Console.WriteLine ("El changuito esta contento porque le gusta la " + fruta.GetType())  ;
    }

    public void Taste (Fruta fruta){
        Console.WriteLine("El changuito cree que la " + fruta.GetType() + " sabe " +fruta.flavor);
    }


    public void Eat(Fruta fruta){
        Console.WriteLine("El changuito comió " + fruta.GetType().ToString() );               
        if(fruta.GetType() == Type.GetType("Rextester.Banana"))
        {
            Happy(fruta);
        } else {
            Sad(fruta);
        }
        Taste(fruta);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola JuanF, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un error en la clase fruta.

Estas asignando:

```
// mal
fflavor = flavor;

// bien
fflavor = value;
```

Por otro lado, no vale la pena que crees una clase heredada con el mismo constructor y sin tener más funcionalidad.
La clase banana debería quedar:

```
class Banana : Fruta
    {
        public Banana() 
           : base("grande", "dulce")
        {

        }
    }
```

Y lo mismo para todas las frutas, para que solamente en main quede:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido al Mundo de Changos");
            Chango chang1 = new Chango();
            Banana ban1 = new Banana();
            chang1.Eat(ban1);

            Chango chang2 = new Chango();
            Limon lim1 = new Limon();
            chang2.Eat(lim1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Así aprovechas la herencia.